# Should i remove my prickly pear?

Tags: cactus, digging

[image]I have a large prickly pear cactus growing closely between a pomegranate tree and a raspberry/loquat tree. Both pomegranate and raspberries need a lot of watering and a cactus of course does not. Also because of the two trees growing closely next to it it isn’t getting much sun and it’s extremely unhealthy. The area it’s growing in just seems like really bad and cluttered placement and the cactus isn’t very healthy so I’m thinking if just digging it up and removing it, thoughts?

i’ve attached a picture of it

Comment: That's a nice prickly pear. Be a shame to lose it, but those loquat and pomegranate aren't going to get any smaller. I'd root some leaves from the cactus before taking it out, then plant in a better place.

Answer (score 1):

I am all in favor of removing misplaced prickly pears. I'm in the middle of removing a huge one from my front yard. If you really want a prickly pear, save a few of the newest pads and plant those.

After you chop it down let dry out some before putting it in the trash, it will weigh less.